# how to write the algorithm for exploding a hierarchy in spherical manner(all parts of assembly should looks like exploded by bomb)

Tags: algorithm, 3d, graph-algorithm, cad

I am writing an algorithm for exploding the parts in spherical manner, Please see the Image[image: Assembly of 125 cubes, each level 25 cubes]

I am developing a behavior name "Explode", in which I am taking explode center point from the end user If user does not specify anything default it is bounding box center of assembly given. I have to explode all parts of assembly such that it looks like a spherical distribution of the part, I also know the radius of explosion(input by the user)

My implementation was to find the vector from explode center to each part and explode as per the distance ratio of that part to the part containing maximum distance to the center which is not the correct way of doing it.
My output is:-

[image: explode view]

Desired output should be like:-

[image: Desired output]

I am not able to think any proper algorithm to explode the part in spherical manner.Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advace

Comment: From this description I'm not sure what you're after, but maybe try to divide your force/offset by a distance of part from the center - so the closest parts move faster. Or show us some sample picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Neeraj Are you trying to achieve something correct as per the laws of physics, or just moving the parts in some shape that looks spherical?

Comment: @kolenda..Thanks for your reply , actually I don't have exact picture of final result. May be we can say that I have to deform this cube shape into a sphere and it should be uniform. I am trying to take account distance ratio of the part to the maximum distance part but I am not getting any particular function to divide such that , it looks like spherical explosion.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for reply, client is asking just move the parts of cube such that final shape after explosion should be visible as sphere. All parts should be distributed uniformly inside that sphere such that end user can see this as exploded view.

Comment: Intuitively, I would suggest that you divide the problem into 4 phases: 1) define a target sphere, 2) assign for each part its target position on the sphere, 3) simulate a trajectory/speed for each part to reach its sphere poisition (a straight line would probably do), and 4) continue by expanding the sphere

Comment: As I see it, the critical phase is 2), because you want to have some uniform distribution of the parts on the sphere. This cannot be achieved if you assume that the movement of each part must be on the line joining it to the center of explosion, a homotecia operation will preserve the shape of th object